# Как программно создать БД OleDB в SilverLight 4?

Tags: silverlight, база-данных, c#

Как программно создать БД OleDB в SilverLight 4?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, этот вопрос некорректен. OleDb - это универсальный интерфейс доступа к данным. Через него можно выполнить SQL-команду. А уже текст команды создания БД зависит от той СУБД, к которой осуществляется подключение через OleDb.

Comment: это понятно, просто в asp.net есть возможность подключить ADOX, и с помощью встроенных методов создавать базы данных, таблицы, sql-запросы... есть ли что-либо аналогичное этому в silverlight????

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду web. То Silverlight является клиентской технологией =>  напрямую работать с бд невозможно. Взгляните в сторону WebSrvice.